# Win2008R2 ASP.NET 3.5 Custom Errors... can't seem to get this to work

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, custom-errors

Help!

I have a custom HttpModule that handles the Application.Error event. The module is working... it logs messages to the event log and I can see these messages... all the way through to the end of the module (after it writes a custom response and calls response.flush()). Roughly speaking the purpose of this module is to log the errors and to show a polite error message to the user (configurable such that the message may/may not contain useful details about the error).

In the application's web.config I have configured <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"> and <customErrors mode="Off" />. In the applicationHost.config I have configured <section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />. Also in the applicationHost.config I have configured <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"> under a <location path="default web site/myvdir"> element.

The "yellow screen of death" is still showing though (for both local requests and remote requests).

This seems to be a Win2008R2 issue... this all works in win2008 (I just now loaded up my test environment and tried this). I doubt it's x64 vs x86 related... but Win2008R2 is x64 only... and my Win2008 test environment is x86.

I've done a bit more poking at this. In Win2008 the <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"> has no bearing. Without the custom error messages are displayed. With it the custom error messages are displayed. On Win2008R2 I see the same problem (yellow screen) regardless of httpErrors/ErrorMode=Detailed.

So... perhaps my real queston is why the <customErrors mode="Off" /> setting just isn't working on IIS7.5. If I set it to "On" I get the short ysod, set of "Off" I get the long ysod (instead of my custom message from http handler, like what happens in IIS7 and IIS6), set to "RemoteOnly" I get the short ysod.

SEMI-SOLVED: The application pool was set to Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated. Switching this to Classic mode allows the custom error details to be displayed. This doesn't explain why IIS7 (win2008 x86) works with Integrated pipeline and IIS7.5 (win2008r2 x64) needing classic pipeline. Any thoughts?

Help immensely appreciated!!!

edit: fix xml tags and added more information and SEMI-SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

`<customErrors>` is just for the asp.net file extensions, for everything else configure `<httpErrors>` too: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors